# How to troubleshoot SQLite Error 5: database is locked?

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I'm building a database kiosk using Microsoft.Data.SQLite. Any database that I use becomes locked with only one method that I use to update a row. Other write methods are fine, but this one causes the app to hang for like 10 seconds and then spits out "Error 5: Database is locked." Also, this method *used* to work, but I'm having an extremely difficult time determining which unrelated change to the app broke it, hence why I'm looking to troubleshoot this issue.

I've ensured that all other database connections are closed. When debugging, everything appears exactly as it's supposed to, but the entire thing hangs at `ExecuteReader().` As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with the command. It works flawlessly when I copy and paste it into SQLite Studio. Here is the entire method. I can go into detail about the lists and stuff if you'd like, but I have ensured that all of the setups for this command are issue-free. Basically, Headers and Data act like the column names and data for a row, and Token is used as a unique identifier for a single item across multiple tables. In this method I add quotes around every item in Data, and join the pairs in Headers and Data together with `", "` to form the `UPDATE` pairs.

```
public static void UpdateRow(string[] _Token, List<string> _Headers, List<string> _Data) // update a row in a table
        {
            string Table = _Token[0];
            string Item = _Token[1];
            string Serial = _Token[2];

            List<string> changes = new List<string>();

            foreach (string str in _Data) // add quotes to every datum
            {
                string str2 = "\"" + str + "\"";
                changes.Add(_Headers[_Data.IndexOf(str)] + " = " + str2); // keep the og str there because indexof needs the unmodified version
            }

            string result = string.Join(", ", changes); // join all the pairs together with ,

            string query = $"Item = \"{Item}\" AND Serial = {Serial}";

            using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection(ConnectionString)) // the db
            {

                SqliteCommand updateCommand = new SqliteCommand //build command
                {
                    Connection = db, // sets db for command to use

                    //UPDATE  Table SET 
                    // header = 'data',
                    // WHERE Item = item AND Serial = serial
                    CommandText = $"UPDATE {Table} SET {result} WHERE {query};"
                };

                db.Open();

                updateCommand.ExecuteReader();

                db.Close();

            }

        }
```

Again, this method previously did not have any issues, but I made so many unrelated changes before testing it again that I cannot for the life of me figure out what might have caused it to stop working. I know that this is probably not the best SQLite implementation and I welcome any improvements and suggestions.

Comment: Start with https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#locked

Comment: What does the debugger show for the literal resolved command text after all of these string shenanigans?

Comment: `UPDATE L SET Item = "LEKO", Serial = "1", FriendlyName = "LekoLite base", Notes = "This will crash", Condition = "Good", Status = "Flown", DateLastService = "2018-12-09 00:59:04", ExpressColumn = "5" WHERE Item = "LEKO" AND Serial = 0001;`   The table and column names are all correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My most recent SQLite operation involved two separate commands, but I was being bad and reusing an `SQLiteCommand` that had parameters. I used the command first to select a row and used two parameters. Then I changed the text but did not use any parameters. I'm not sure if it was the disused parameters or just re-using the command in general that was causing the issue, but using a new command for the second operation resulted in the database connection actually closing.

I troubleshooted this issue by breaking at every single database operation I was doing. After I stepped through each one to make sure it was working as expected, I executed a basic `UPDATE` command in SQLite Studio. I found the errant operation when SQLite Studio hung after the operation was finished.